# Writing a HTTP request and response should be encoded in JSON

Tags: json, web-services, rest, http, soap

**Q1** - Write the HTTP1/1 request that retrieves the country for the IP 128.54.56.121 and the response should be encoded in JSON.

`GET 128.54.56.121 HTTP/1.1
HOST: http://api.example.org/geoip
Content-Type: application/Json
Connection: Close`

Am I writing it right? I don't have where to test it? based on the sentence: *The WEB Service expects a GET request with an IPv4 in the query part of the URL(The key for ipv4 value should be IP)*

**Q2** - Write down the corresponding HTTP Response for the HTTP request above. The web service responds with the folowing data: {"Country": "England", "isoCode": "UK"}

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: 11.10.2016
Server: Apache
{"Country": "England", "isoCode": "UK"}
```

I am not sure if I am doing it right or not, could someone please have a look at this code. Do I need to add/remove some lines or add something what is missing in this code?

Comment: SO is for question and answers. Please post your code snippet with issues you're facing and research you did instead of posting your requirements.

Comment: @jeevatkm Well, as I mentioned I don't know how to test it in order to know if there is any problem or not. Thas why i am asking. Thank you

Comment: Actually you're asking `write the HTTP/1.1 request`, have you written a code for this? which programming language you're using? which geoip lookup service you're using? are you asking in SO, how to test web service? ... Anyway as a sample freegeoip.net is one of the free geoip lookup service http://freegeoip.net/json/128.54.56.121 (I'm not sure this is relevant here or not...)